# Minting a new position in UniswapV3 with ethers

Tags: ethers.js, uniswapv3

I'm trying to mint a new position with this function:

```
export const newMint = async (
  token0: string,
  token1: string,
  fee: number,
  tickLower: number,
  tickUpper: number,
  amount0Desired: string,
  amount1Desired: string,
  amount0Min: number,
  amount1Min: number,
  recipient: string,
  deadline: number
) => {
  try {
    const signer = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum).getSigner()
    const nonfungible = new ethers.Contract(
      nftAddress,
      positionManagerABI,
      signer
    )


    const data = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
      [
        "address", 
        "address",
        'uint24',
        'int24',
        'int24',
        'uint256',
        'uint256',
        'uint256',
        'uint256',
        'address',
        'uint256'     
      ],
      [
        token0,
        token1,
        fee,
        tickLower,
        tickUpper,
        amount0Desired,
        amount1Desired,
        amount0Min,
        amount1Min,
        recipient,
        deadline
      ]
    )
    nonfungible.mint(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, "this is the error for newMinting")
    console.log(
      token0,
      token1,
      fee,
      tickLower,
      tickUpper,
      amount0Desired,
      amount1Desired,
      amount0Min,
      amount1Min,
      recipient,
      deadline      
    )
  }
}
```

I'm calling it correctly through this call:

```
  const addLiquidity = () => {
    newMint(
      token0,
      token1,
      3000,
      -887220,
      887220,
      String(Number(ethers.utils.parseEther(formattedAmounts[Field.INPUT])) * ether),
      String(Number(ethers.utils.parseEther(formattedAmounts[Field.OUTPUT])) * ether),
      0,
      0,
      userAddress,
      tS + 3000
    )
  }
```

Getting the timestamp through this function:

```
export const timestamp = async () => {
  try {
    const block = await provider.getBlock('latest')
    return block
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, 'error for timestamp')
  }
}
```

I think that everything is ok with the params, the problem is to encode the struct:

```
    struct MintParams {
        address token0;
        address token1;
        uint24 fee;
        int24 tickLower;
        int24 tickUpper;
        uint256 amount0Desired;
        uint256 amount1Desired;
        uint256 amount0Min;
        uint256 amount1Min;
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
    }
```

My idea is that `ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode` does not fit as the best approach. Can someone give me a hint over this?

The error:

```
Error: unexpected character at position 46 (argument="param", value="struct INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams params", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.6.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Insteed of a human readable abi i used the abi provider by UniswapV3Periphery.